# MYSQL SELECT clause giving unwanted results. Multiple WHERE AND statements

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, where-clause

```
SELECT `post`.*, `user_account`.`project_name` 
FROM 
`post` 
INNER JOIN `user_account` ON `post`.`user_id` = `user_account`.`user_id` 
WHERE 
`post`.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
AND `is_active` = 1 
AND `deleted_at` IS NULL 
AND `end` > '2013-10-09' 
AND `user_account`.`project_name` LIKE '%intensiivkursus%' 
OR ( 
`title` LIKE '%intensiivkursus%' 
OR `topics` LIKE '%intensiivkursus%' 
OR `target_group` LIKE '%intensiivkursus%' 
OR `lectors` LIKE '%intensiivkursus%' 
OR `timetable` LIKE '%intensiivkursus%' 
) 
GROUP BY 
`post`.`id` 
ORDER BY 
`post`.`created_at` DESC
```

I would expect this to give results only with `is_active = 1`, but for some reason, it gives the opposite. I get 5 results, all with `is_active = 0` 
What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suspect a problem with your OR / AND and parenthesis. Operator's precedence does the confusing thing.

Don't you mean

```
AND 
(`user_account`.`project_name` LIKE '%intensiivkursus%' 
OR `title` LIKE '%intensiivkursus%' 
OR `topics` LIKE '%intensiivkursus%' 
OR `target_group` LIKE '%intensiivkursus%' 
OR `lectors` LIKE '%intensiivkursus%' 
OR `timetable` LIKE '%intensiivkursus%' 
)
```

or maybe

```
AND `user_account`.`project_name` LIKE '%intensiivkursus%' 
AND ( 
`title` LIKE '%intensiivkursus%' 
OR `topics` LIKE '%intensiivkursus%' 
OR `target_group` LIKE '%intensiivkursus%' 
OR `lectors` LIKE '%intensiivkursus%' 
OR `timetable` LIKE '%intensiivkursus%' 
)
```

Comment: @ruuter I always check three times when I've got an OR outside parenthesis. It might be needed, of course, and it's perfeclty valid if you manage operator's precedence, but not that often

Comment: Yeah, thank you, that was it. So simple, but confusing indeed, specially when you awake 26th hour :p